# Most Profit Assigning Work Problem from Leetcode (Problem no. 826)

Tags: c++, greedy, maximum-profit-problem

I have been trying to solve this problem on leetcode (https://leetcode.com/problems/most-profit-assigning-work/) whose problem description goes like this :

> We have jobs: difficulty[i] is the difficulty of the ith job, and
> profit[i] is the profit of the ith job. Now we have some workers.
> worker[i] is the ability of the ith worker, which means that this
> worker can only complete a job with difficulty at most worker[i]. 
> Every worker can be assigned at most one job, but one job can be
> completed multiple times. For example, if 3 people attempt the same
> job that pays $1, then the total profit will be $3.  If a worker
> cannot complete any job, his profit is $0. What is the most profit we
> can make? 
>  For example : Input: difficulty = [2,4,6,8,10], profit
> = [10,20,30,40,50], worker = [4,5,6,7] Output: 100  
>  Explanation: Workers are assigned jobs of difficulty [4,4,6,6] and they get profit
> of [20,20,30,30] separately.

I have tried solving using this code,

```
class Solution {
public:
    int maxProfitAssignment(vector<int>& difficulty, vector<int>& profit, vector<int>& worker) {

        map <int,int> map;
        int sum = 0;
        int j = 0;
        
        // creating a hash map for profit and difficulty
        for (int i = 0; i < profit.size(); i++) {
            map.insert({profit[i], difficulty[i]});
        }
  
        //sorting the workers vector in descending order
        sort(worker.begin(), worker.end(),  greater<int>());

        //Iterating through the hash map in descending order of Profit (high profit to low profit) 
        for (auto i = map.rbegin(); i != map.rend(); i++) {

            // Assigning the job with higher profit to the workers who have difficulty
            // greater than equal to the difficulty of the job
            while(j < worker.size()) {
                if (worker[j] >= (i->second)) {
                    sum += i->first;
                    j++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }                
            }
        }
        return sum; 
    }
};
```

But my code isn't passing a test case. I'm attaching the link to the test case. https://notepad.pw/r7dv12cv (It is too big to paste here)

> ```
> My output       : 999481607
> Expected output : 999542181
> ```

I'm unable to find where the issue is arising. It has passed all the test cases except this. 
Please go through the code and run it on leetcode platform if you can. Please let me know where I have gone wrong.

Comment: What is the test case that is failing? It should be in the question, not at an external link that requires a login. How does your output differ from the expected output? Have you done anything to try and narrow down the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @RetiredNinja. I have attached the notepad link of the test case as it is too big to paste here. I have added the ouputs as well.

Comment: can a more difficult job gives you less profit?